# How to write unittests when using Siena on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit, wicket, siena

I'm writing a webapp which uses Wicket and Siena/gae as datastore.
Now I want to write some decent unittests for my services.
Is there already a toolset or classes that make the mocking of siena models a bit more easy?

Note that I don't use playframework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE in development is quite easy to use, this is almost a memory DB so it's very light and practical.

Thus, if you want to mock Siena models, there are no specific classes for this. But as it's using ActiveRecord pattern